# Ionic 4 - Global SCSS Replace 'ion-card' magins?

Tags: ionic-framework, components, ionic4

`<ion-card>` has a default margin of 10px on all sides of the box element.  I would like for there to be 0px of margin around these elements.

I am unable to replace this in global styles using both the `ion-card` and `.sc-ion-card-md-h` selectors (and pretty sure the latter would only work when md/android is applied).

I have been able to select *some* other elements globally, but *most* high-level components are acting in this manner where I cannot replace them globally.. my styles simply don't show up in the element inspect for the `<ion-card>` element.

It seems as if there's something within these "shadow-root" `<style>` elements that I am unable to target and overwrite the styles off unless I'm on a deep-component level of SCSS files; however, I really need these styles to be replaced globally to avoid having to copy/paste CSS into every component (as these `<ion-card>` literally exist on every page of my app.

For instance, with the below code neither my cards nor my card titles backgrounds turn red.. nor do these CSS styles show up when inspecting the page anywhere in the element styles window.  But, if I use body as a selector the body turns red which means my global styles ARE being loaded and I am just unable to select these components:

```
ion-card,
.sc-ion-card-md-h,
ion-card-title {
    --background: red !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

If I put these same styles inside my `home.page.scss` which has posts on it, the styles do apply (I think that's because I am targeting the slot inside that page).  Why does it only work at a component-level and not a global level?

Any ideas on how to properly target these components at a global level?

Answer (score 0):

Use `::ng-deep` to cascade the style to children.